# How to Sort Out Drive Letters from Powershell Output

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-administration

So I am trying to make a for loop that will optimize the drives based on anyone's drives in windows. 
I have the following command and know how to structure the for loop. I just need the command to jkust print the drive letters. Is there a way to do this with the `Get-PSDrive` command?

```bsh
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                   CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                   ---------------
C                1311.02        550.33 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                   WINDOWS\system32
D                 557.70        140.94 FileSystem    D:\
E                   0.22          0.46 FileSystem    E:\
F                   0.00        369.97 FileSystem    F:\
H                   0.23          1.14 FileSystem    H:\
J                1676.01          0.64 FileSystem    J:\
O                 899.72         31.79 FileSystem    O:\
```

How can I just print the drive names without the column name?

Comment: `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select root -ExpandProperty root` or substitute `name` for `root`

Comment: a very slight variation on the version by `Itchydon` ... [1] just the letter >>> `(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name` <<< and [2] the full "C:\" >>> `(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root` <<<

Comment: I realize we sometimes feel guilty about the simplicity of the answers but both of your posts are in fact, answers to his question and should be submitted as such.  Otherwise, this question will stay open unless the OP answers it himself and you gents won't get any credit for your assistance.

Comment: It works, but I need the ```:\``` to be taken out, how can I do that? I am familiar with Regex on Linux not so much with Windows Powershell I guess with `tr`?

Comment: ("string").Replace('stri', 'tho'), or in your case .Replace(':\', '') and if you just use the Name property, instead of Root, it's already trimmed out.

Comment: @thepip3r - good point ... done. [*grin*]

Comment: @thepip3r - ..and that's a good point from me too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two ways to get the drive info you my seem to want from that cmdlet. one gets *just* the letter [the `.Name`, ex = C], and the other gets the root of the drive [the `.Root`, ex = C:\].

drive letter only ...

```
(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name
# result is an array of just the drive letters
#    C, D, E, etc.
```

the root of the drives ...

```
(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root
# result is an array of drive roots
#    C:\, D:\, E:\, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you @Lee_Dailey

Comment: (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name did the trick for me.

Comment: @R.Barrett - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]